# Problem with setting visibility of controls in child master page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, nested

I have a parent master page (Master.Master) and child master page (Child.Master). The Child.Master inherits Master.Master master page file. Now in the Child.Master i want to set the visibility of Div (whose ID is Div1) to false, for which i'm using the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.FindControl("Div1").Visible = false;
}
```

Here is the code in the Child Master Page file:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Webstore.Master.cs" Inherits="WebStore.WebStoreMaster" MasterPageFile="~/Login.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="UserMaster" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">    
<div id="Div1" runat="server">
<div id="Sidebar" runat="server" style="float: left; margin-top: 100px; margin-right: 20px;">
</div>
</div>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</asp:Content>
```

The compiler is giving me the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can someone explain why is it happening so ??

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: have you confirmed, via using a view source in the browser, that the div renders with the expected id? (id="div1"). Is the child.master being loaded dynamically?

Comment: Is the `<Div />` defined in parent master or child master page?

Comment: @Bala in the child master page

Comment: And this is the Page_Load of the child master? or the content page?

Comment: @Bala Page_Load of the child master page

Comment: Is the Div nested in some other container ?

Comment: @yes it is nested in the <asp:Content></asp:Content> container. I have edited my question and added child master page code.

Comment: @Cos what a silly question u asked what is theconcerned of it rendering it on browser with the expected id, he is making it on server-side...

Comment: @user653622 try setting MasterType directive and then FindControl

Comment: @PeachLabs, you are (of course) correct... I have been doing so much work in jquery lately that I sometime forget where I am at, when looking at code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

In this case, if the div is a top level element, and you are in the page_load of the child master page in which the div resides, you should just be able to do

```
Div1.Visible = false;
```

Why not use a Panel control?

Comment: @yes there is a runat attribute

Comment: @PeachLabs, he just included the markup. i'll delete my answer shortly.

Comment: That worked like a charm. It took some time to work as i was doing a silly mistake from my side. Thanks for your help and immediate feedback. Truly appreciate your endeavour

Answer (score 2):

you should say

```
this.Master.FindControl("Div1").Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting @MasterType in Content Pages and in Child Master Pages. Below are some reference links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx

http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/back-basics-%E2%80%93-using-mastertype?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zones%2Fdotnet+%28.NET+Zone%29

http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/haissam/archive/2008/02/11/mastertype-directive-in-content-page.aspx

Thanks

Comment: where should i set the MasterType directive, is it in the parent master page or in the child master page ?

Comment: @user65 as I mention in the first line you can set the directive in Child MasterPages and Content Pages as well.

Answer (score 1):

Master page is loaded is after page_load. Therefore when you attempt to address the master page during page_load it's properties and methods are not yet available. Move this down in the page life cycle. [ASP.NET Page Life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), [Another SO answer on Masterpage/page life cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716094/purpose-of-different-order-of-execution-init-and-load). the child master is loaded during the page_load, and parent master is loaded during the child master page_load.